# Testing Facebook Native iOS App

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios5, app-store-connect

I would like to integrate Facebook into an iOS application I am building, however it seems there is no way to set up a Facebook 'Native iOS Application' with an iOS application that is not already published and available in the App Store.

When I Set up a Native iOS Application for my Facebook App from my Facebook developer's account it requires that I fill in my App Store ID. However when I submit I get the following error message:

> Your iPhone App Store ID is invalid because the iTunes App Store
>   reports your app as being unavailable for iPhone and iPod touch.

I have set up my application on iTunes Connect, but I have not submitted my binary yet as I am in the process of building it, so I assume that this message is due to it being unavailable on the App Store.

This seems like a catch 22 situation. I can't test my app until its in the App Store but I can't get my app in the AppStore until I have tested (and built) it. How can I test my iOS application with Facebook before release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been there, but the solutions is simple.

Don't fill out the Facebook 'Native iOS Application'!
For testing all you needed is the Facebook appid.

Comment: What exactly do u mean all you need is the Facebook appid? I turned off the Native iOS Application part of the form in the Facebook App settings. It still wont deep link into my app, which is not yet published. I have setup the handling of open URL as my app is able to seamlessly log in with facebook.

Comment: Did you add the `fb<appid>` to the info.plist? Also you don't want to turn the Native iOS Application off just don't fill in the AppStore ID.

Answer (score 0):

Later on in the Deep Linking portion of the iOS Facebook Tutorial, it also mentions the AppStore ID and that you can use somebody else's ID temporarily to get all the data to save. They just say to make sure you use your own id when you finally do publish the app.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think **facebook Native iOS App** settings are necessary. I have done facebook login with it in two of my apps and without it in one of my app and all are running well. Here are workaround by me:
[Native iOS Facebook SSO won't return to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625210/native-ios-facebook-sso-wont-return-to-app/20971808#20971808)