# Native iOS Facebook SSO won't return to app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

Ok this may seem like a duplicate but I've been through all of the questions that center around the issue and I still can't seem to get this to work for my app.

I have followed the iOS tutorial on the Facebook Developer site and I have done the following:

1. Created a Facebook App to get the Facebook App ID.
2. I've assigned this App ID to a constant and I use it to initialize the Facebook object within my app.
3. I've made sure my app is flagged for multitasking
4. I've setup the fbAPP_ID in the plist under the URLs drop down
5. I've made my AppDelegate a FBSessionDelegate and implemented very simple fbDidLogin and fbDidNotLogin delegate methods.

Versions: XCode 4.3.2 on Lion, iOS 5.1, Facebook iOS 4.1.1

All of this and I still can't seem to get Facebook to return control back to my app when it authorizes. It just stays in Facebook instead.

Code: (Note FB_APP_ID changed to basic number for viewing here)

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

#define FB_APP_ID @"1234567890"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Facebook* facebook;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize facebook = _facebook;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:FB_APP_ID andDelegate:self];
    if (![_facebook isSessionValid])
    {
        [_facebook authorize:nil];
    }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [_facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [_facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (void)fbDidLogin
{
    NSLog(@"App logged in");
}

- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
{
    NSLog(@"App did not login");
}

@end
```

Relevant Info.plist porton:

[image]

Facebook App screen (mostly pinked out):

[image: Facebook App screen]

Note: I tried it with only basic settings and also with the iOS Native app settings with a fake iTunes store ID but the same bundle ID from my provisioning profile.

No matter what I do it always loads up Facebook and asks to authorize my app and then it simply closes the auth screen window and sits there on my Facebook screen instead of returning to my app.

Also note: I know it will always ask because I'm not checking for the auth token and expiration date.....that's the next step....for now I want to at least get it to return to my app before I worry about that.

Have I missed something here? Anything else I can try to get Facebook to return to my app?

EDIT: Also when debugging, I can't seem to find any spot where either openURL is called for some reason.

EDIT #2: When running it on the simulator, it loads up the FB Dialog via Safari (as expected) and then when I authorize, safari throws an error as if the URL they are trying to use to get back to my app is invalid:

[image: simulator safari error]

This still doesn't tell me much since my fb1234567890 is setup right as far as I know in the Info.plist.

Comment: were you able to login atleast once ?

Comment: The problem isn't logging in. Facebook pops up just fine and I can click Authorize or whatever.....but it never returns to the app...it just stays in Facebook

Comment: put a breakpoint or a NSLog in handleOpenURL and check if its getting called at all and also have you given your app a unique URL to which safari will redirect to ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/
Read after step 6.

Comment: Neither of the handleOpenUrl calls seem to be being called when I debug it. As far as a unique URL, I thought that's what the plist part was for (as shown above) where I use fbAPP_ID ? And step 6 and beyond goes into Graph and Feeds. At this point, I'm just trying to get basic SSO working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your info.plist seems to be formatted incorrectly

Ensure that the url scheme is nested under an item (an array to be exact) called "URL Schemes"

This array should contain all possible URL Schemes that can launch your app

See the attached image for a better explanation of URL Schemes

[image: url scheme]

Also, the "URL identifier" should be your bundle identifier: ex. com.mycompany.myapp
This should match the identifier you provide on your provisioning profiles

hope this helps!

Comment: you sir are simply awesome =) THANK YOU!

Comment: You're welcome! I also just implemented Facebook SSO, best of luck!

Comment: @SRandazzo I was missing `URL Identifier` and still everything was working as expected but some times when I hit `Okay` button on fb sso safari, It displayed my app's default screen but then just exited without continuing to flow. is the missing `URL Identifier` a problem?

Comment: I'm also having same problem. I did the same as you said. But it won't work.  Kindly have a look at (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390170/facebook-integration-v4-0-not-working-for-iphone-app?noredirect=1#comment46957737_29390170)

Answer (score 3):

#### All you have to follow these steps

#### STEP 1:

Facebook developer side stuff:

If your app is already submitted then fill iphone/ipad appstore id otherwise leave it empty.
[image: facebook developer account app id settings]

#### STEP 2:

Next in your XCode:

Goto
`Target > Info > URL Types` > click plus icon and add the items like this-
[image: URL Scheme settings]

In my application, there were both options to login via facebook and google so I created two URL Types. You can see second one are Facebook URL Type settings. URL Scheme will be your facebook app id from facebook Developer account with `fb` at starts. So if your facebook developer app id is `9876543267575645` then URL Scheme will become `fb9876543267575645`.

#### STEP 3:

Next, you have to add a new key in info.plist. So remain in same screen and add `FacebookAppID` like this screen:
[image: info.plist settings]

All this stuff will bring your app back after successful facebook oauth.

#### STEP 4:

Rest you will do in your `AppDelegate` class. Simply add this method in `AppDelegate.m`

```
NSString *retURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url];    
if ([retURL rangeOfString:facebookid].location != NSNotFound)
{
    // if your application is coming back from facebook native app.
    return [_facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
else
{
    // if your app is coming back from google plus oauth.
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

during all this, must intialise and  synthesize `facebook` instance in `AppDelegate.m`

```
@synthesize facebook = _facebook;
```

and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:facebookid];
    // rest of your code is already here......
}
```

One more important thing. During I was implementing these steps, I also did too much research to achieve this and finally the working stuff is here. I made these settings in two of my apps.

But while I was creating third app, I started from beginning and did not follow **STEP 1** and **STEP 3** and voila.... redirection works! So i don't think facebook developer account **Native iOS App** settings are necessary while you are making Facebook login in your app..

Answer (score 2):

I ran into another issue. I edited the raw Info.plist file and added:

```
<key>URL Types</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>URL Schemes</key>
        <array>
             <string>fbxxxxxxxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

That didn't work because the keys are not 'URL Types', 'URL Schemes' and 'URL Identifier', it's 'CFBundleURLTypes' , 'CFBundleURLSchemes' and 'CFBundleURLIdentifier' instead. Xcode will rename that in the editor to 'URL Types', 'URL Schemes' and 'URL Identifier'.

To be sure select the Info.plist in xcode, right click->show raw keys/values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of the above, or other answers on SO, worked for me, though I seemed to have the exact same issue.

However, when I enabled "Deep Linking", it worked perfectly, so it may have been a combination of all of the above AND enabling that option too.