# Facebook SSO IOS do not return to app

Tags: ios, facebook

We use Facebook SSO in our application. On clicking Facebook login app goes to Facebook app, displays login. But after login it won't return to app. But if a user is already logged in Facebook app, login button click switches to Facebook app and shows permission dialog. On clicking allow it returns to app. Is it the default behavior? Or is there any problem with my code or our Facebook app settings? Thanks in advance.

```
SHAppDelegate *appDelegate = [SHAppDelegate application];
NSArray * permissions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:FACEBBOK_PERMISSION, nil];
  if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    appDelegate.session = [[[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions] autorelease];
    if (appDelegate.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                         FBSessionState status, 
                                                         NSError *error) {
            [self updateView];
        }];
    }
}
if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
} else
{
    if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }

    // if the session isn't open, let's open it now and present the login UX to the user
    [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, 
                                                     FBSessionState status, 
                                                     NSError *error) {
        // and here we make sure to update our UX according to the new session state
        [self updateView];
    }];
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in the plist. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625210/native-ios-facebook-sso-wont-return-to-app

Comment: This is a known issue on the Facebook end. You can follow it here:

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. This is not a .plist trouble - without URLSchemes(with fbXXXXX) facebook app and safari never return to you application.
In this case, the Faccebook app does not return only when the user is not logged in it.
Safari handles this situation correctly. The same way a Facebook app does not return control if the user canceled the permissions confirmation.
In other situations, all right.