# How to redirect on app after successfull facebook login in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, ios-simulator, ios5.1

There is a facebook button in my app in login screen ,when user click on this button facebook login page open in browse and after successful login application redirect and display next page . Please hep mw with example .

IOS version : 5.0 
ARC project

Thank You

Comment: are you successfully login with facebook or not...? you got accessToken.. ?

Comment: yes i login successfully  and got access token ...But my need to open login page on browser and redirect app ..How to implement such thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the way you guys can visit my reply here [Native iOS Facebook SSO won't return to app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625210/native-ios-facebook-sso-wont-return-to-app/20971808#20971808)

In my application i had to implement facebook and googleplus both and finally I made it successfully. I dont think facebook developer app portal needs any edit rather than getting appid. I made three apps with facebook login, one of them does not have **iOS Native App** setting in facebook developer app but that app's login part is also running well.

Answer (score 1):

in your you  AppDelegate modify the method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url  
{

    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];

    if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"fb://xxxxxxxxxxxx"]) {
        [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
        returnValue = YES;
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

xxx will be your facebookappid

But keep in mind that this is not triggered in IOS 6.In ios 6 the following method will be triggered.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

   return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

If the state of your session changes due to login or disconnect FBsession calls the following method and you should handle your cases.

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState)state
                  error:(NSError *)error {
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen: {
        //update permissionsArrat
        [self retrieveUSerPermissions];

        if (!needstoReopenOldSession) {
            //First User information
            [self getUserInformation:nil];
        }

        NSNotification *authorizationNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:facebookAuthorizationNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:authorizationNotification];

    }
    case FBSessionStateClosed: {
        break;
    }
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
}

if (error) {
    NSNotification *authorizationNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:faceBookErrorOccuredNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:authorizationNotification];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use this official [tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/#step2) and you will be OK. See the 2-d point for your problem as well.